# Add new symbol for MT4ManagerAPI

Tags: c++, mt4

I get the `MT4ManagerAPI.h` from the metaquotes. Now I would like to add new symbol to the meta server but apparently its not working and keep throwing error code for me. There is so limited source and discussion for the API and I found nothing related to add new symbol on MT4ManagerAPi so any help is appreciated.

My code:

```
logger.info("Conencting to ... " + address);
CManagerFactory factory;
CManagerInterface* manager;
factory.Init("mtmanapi.dll");
factory.WinsockStartup();
if (factory.IsValid() == FALSE)
{
    logger.error("Failed to Load Libraries");
    return;
}
manager = factory.Create(ManAPIVersion);
if (manager == NULL) {
    logger.error("Failed to create MetaTrader 4 Manager API interface");
    return;
}
if (manager->Connect(address.c_str())!=RET_OK) {
    logger.error("Connection to MT4 server failed");
    return;
}
if (manager->Login(id, password.c_str()) != RET_OK) {
    logger.error("Login Failed");
    return;
}
logger.info("Connection Established...");
std::string myString = "Hello, LPCSTR!";
LPCSTR lpcstr = myString.c_str();
std::cout << manager->SymbolAdd(lpcstr); // it returns value 2 which means general error according to the API
```

Code from MT4ManagerAPI:

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                           Result codes                           |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
enum
  {
   //--- common errors
   RET_OK                =0,        // all OK
   RET_OK_NONE,                     // all OK-no operation
   RET_ERROR,                       // general error

   ... and the rest

Add symbol function
//--- symbols
   virtual int          __stdcall SymbolsRefresh()                           =0;
   virtual ConSymbol*   __stdcall SymbolsGetAll(int *total)                  =0;
   virtual int          __stdcall SymbolGet(LPCSTR symbol,ConSymbol *cs)     =0;
   virtual int          __stdcall SymbolInfoGet(LPCSTR symbol,SymbolInfo *si)=0;
   virtual int          __stdcall SymbolAdd(LPCSTR symbol)                   =0;
   virtual int          __stdcall SymbolHide(LPCSTR symbol)                  =0;
```